# Change My Domain Without Losing Old Emails

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, web-hosting, whm

I'm concerned about losing emails during changeing my domain nem, Lets say I have **domain1.com** and there's an email associated with this domain info@domain1.com .. If I want to change my domain and purchase a new one **domain2.com**,

**Is it possible to keep old emails the received on info@domain1.com and change it to info@domain2.com ?**

I'm all set to change the Nameservers on the domain, but I'm not sure that I'm safe with the emails sent to these accounts during the transfer process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both info@domain1.com and info@domain2.com are separate IMAP accounts then you can use a service like https://www.yippiemove.com/ to migrate emails/directories between the two. Once everything has migrated to domain2.com then you can close down domain1.com